# Php crashes when mean, median, and mode are reached

Tags: php, crash, mean, median, mode

Me and my group are making a research paper on Pascal and Php, and for the last step we have to make a simple program that calculates the floating point numbers into mean, median, and mode. However, the program refuses to run on my partner's NetBeans PHP IDE along with my Visual Basic.

```
<?php
        
        $Numbers= array(20);
        $Mean=0;
     
         //these functions are called 
         getNumbers();
         calMean();
         NumbersaboveMean();
         calMedian();
         calMode();
         Mode();
         
        //this function gets the numbers from the user
        function getNumbers()
        {        
          $temp=0;         
          echo " Enter up to 10 float point numbers ";   
             
          for( $n=0; $n<20; $n++)
        {
        $Number[$n]=(float)readline('Enter a number: ');//gets the number from the user    
        }
              
         //This arranges the numbers in order from least to greatest
         for( $n=0; $n<20; $n++)
        {
               $temp=$Number[$n];
               $Number[$n]=$Number[$n+1];
               $Number[$n+1]=$temp;                       
        } 
        
        }
        
        //This function calculates the mean
        function calMean()
     {
        
        for( $n=0; $n<20; $n++)
        {
           $sum=$sum+$Number[$n];             
        }
        
        $Mean=$sum/(20);
        
         echo "The mean of your numbers is " + $Mean;
     }
     
     // funciton determines how many numbers are above the mean
       function NumbersaboveMean()
     {
         $track=0;
         
         for($n=0;$n<20;$n++)
        {
           if($Number[$n]>$Mean)
           {
                $track++;
           }
        }
           echo " There are " + $track + " numbers above the mean."; 
      }  
      
      //determines what the median is
     function calMedian()
     {
          $median=Number[10];  
         
          echo "The median of your numbers is " + $median;         
     }
     
     //this function determines what the mode is 
     function calMode()
     {       
          $mode=0;
         $count=0;
         $count2=0;
         $md2=0;
         
         for($n=0;$n<18;$n++)
        {
           if($Number[$n]===$Number[$n+1])
           {
               $count2++;                 
           }         
           if(count==count2)
           {
               $count=$count2;
               $count2=0;
               $md2=1;
           }
           
           else if(count<count2)
           {
               $mode=$Number[$n];
               $count=$count2;
               $count2=0;
           }        
        }

     }
     
       //determines if there is 1 mode or more 
       function mode()
        {  
         if(md2>0)
           {
               echo "There is more than 1 mode.";
           }
         
         else
         {
             echo "The mode is " + mode;
         }
         
        }
     
        ?>
```

When I run it, I get to about 10+ loops of inputting numbers before it crashes with "Code has exited with -1 (FFFFFF~~~) (something something i will update it when I get my pc back in a few hours.

To be honest, we really don't need a fix to the not running we just want to know if the code does it we want it too.

Comment: To check if the code is doing what you want it to do, you might want to write simple tests of some sort that check each function and print out data so that you can verify the numbers are what you expect from the functions. If you want to get more formal with the testing, [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/) might be something you could use for this.

Comment: Another tip for future reference is that you might want to add arguments to at least some of your functions. For example, you might want to pass an array of your numbers to your `calMean()` function, like this: `calMean($numbers)`. To be able to do this, you would also need to add a `$numbers` variable to your function definition, like this: `function calMean($numbers) { ... }`. Then, you can use the `$numbers` variable inside of your function for further work.